# JQuery Stop() method for animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need a way of stopping an animation that is triggered on `mouse enter()` in it's tracks if the `mouse leave()`. At the moment this code means that if the user scrolls in and then out quickly the animation will complete the `mouse enter()` animation and then perform the `mouse leave()` function in order rather than stop it in it's track on mouse leave and animate out from there.

I believe this can be done with the `stop()` function but I do not know how to use it.

```
$(".featuredslider a").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).stop();
        $(this).find('.smallcont').animate({opacity:0},400);
        $(this).find('.bigcont').animate({opacity:1},400);
    });
    $(".featuredslider a").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).stop();
        $(this).find('.smallcont').animate({opacity:1},400);
        $(this).find('.bigcont').animate({opacity:0},400);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is [here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

But it's quite straight forward, i believe you want something like :

```
$(".featuredslider a").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('.smallcont').stop().animate({opacity:0},400);
    $(this).find('.bigcont').stop().animate({opacity:1},400);
});
$(".featuredslider a").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('.smallcont').stop().animate({opacity:1},400);
    $(this).find('.bigcont').stop().animate({opacity:0},400);
});
```

This will stop any animations already started on each object then start the `animate()` function after the `stop()`

Comment: No probs ... :-) glad I could help